# How To Test for Android File Chooser Availability

Tags: android-afilechooser

I'm trying to test for file chooser availability. I assumed an error would be returned if none was available, however, this is not the case.

Here's my code:

```
public void doImport() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("file/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Import"), IMPORT_RACES_CODE);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
                Utils.Error(this, "THERE WAS NO NAVIGATOR FOUND, Install a navigator!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Utils.Error(this, "Some other error occurred!");
        }
    }
```

No Exception is being sent back to my routine, though.  The OS seems to be handling the error and generating a dialog box stating "No apps can perform this action."

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, found the answer in this thread:

[Android : Can I use this intent from a 3rd party application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336088/android-can-i-use-this-intent-from-a-3rd-party-application)

See the "isIntentAvailable" routine posted by the responder.

Thanks, all!